# find nth-smallest value across m sorted arrays using idea from 2 sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

May I ask whether would it be possible? the general approach would be somehow like find n-th value on two sorted array, to ignore the insignificants and try to focus on the rest by adjusting the value of n in recursion

The 2 sorted arrays problem would yield a computation time O(log(|A|)+log(|B|), while the question is similar, I would like to ask if there exist algorithm for m sorted arrays for time O(log(|A1|)+log(|A2|)+...+log(|Am|)),

or some similar variation that is near the time I mentioned above (due to the variable m, we might need some other sorting algorithm for the pivots from those arrays),

or if such algorithm doesn't exist, why?

I just can't find this algorithm from googling

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Do you mean nth-smallest, across all the m arrays? Or something else?

Comment: @smci: What else would he/she mean? I don't see another sensible interpretation

Comment: the abovementioned is exactly the case, thanks :p

Comment: @Niklas-B: many other possibilities, since he/she went on to to say **'find n-th value on two sorted array'**. So it wasn't even clear whether they were talking about 2 or m arrays, or the intermediate mergesort of 2 from the m arrays, or what. Why not help edit the question for clarity?

Comment: I knew I saw a similar question - so I googled for the title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753345/finding-kth-smallest-number-from-n-sorted-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple randomized algorithm:

1. Select a pivot randomly from any of the *m* arrays. Let's call it *x*
2. For every array, do a binary search for *x* to find out how many values *< x* are in the array. Say we have *r<sub>i</sub>* values *< x* in array *i*. We know that *x* has rank *r = sum(i = 1 to m, r<sub>i</sub>)* in the union of all arrays.
3. If *n <= r*, we restrict each array *i* to the indices *0...(r<sub>i</sub> - 1)* and recurse. If *n > r*, we restrict each array to the indices *r<sub>i</sub>...|A<sub>i</sub> | - 1*
4. repeat

The expected recursion depth is *O(log(N))* with *N* being the total number of elements, with a proof similar to that of Quickselect, so the expected running time is something like *O(m * log<sup>2</sup>(N))*.

The paper ["Generalized Selection and Ranking" by Frederickson and Johnson](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804690) proposes selection and ranking algorithms for different scenarios, for example an *O(m + c * log(k/c))* algorithm to select the k-th element from *m* equally sized sorted sequences, with *c = min{m, k}*.

Comment: quite impressive, but i was actually expecting some algorithm that is as efficient as shown in this topic:

[Find n-th smallest value in two sorted arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686823/given-2-sorted-arrays-of-integers-find-the-nth-largest-number-in-sublinear-time)

i.e. just extend the case to m arrays, simply brainstorming it should be possible in O(log(|A1|)+log(|A2|)+...+log(|Am|)) but how should the implementation be for variable m?

I would add this to my topic, thanks for your work again ><

Comment: @orb have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182488/median-of-5-sorted-arrays ?