# Find kth smallest element from two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Given two sorted array of size M and N. I was trying to implement an algorithm with time complexity O(logM+logN). The strategy is basically comparing the middle index elements from two subarray based on their length condition.

```
    // Test case 1
    // Works for all position except when kth is 6
    int[] num1 = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int[] num2 = {1,2,3,4,5};

    // Test case 2
    // Always print the next smallest element
    int[] num3 = {1,3,5,7,9};
    int[] num4 = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,30,40,50,56,77,35};


public static int findKth(int[] A, int p1, int r1, int[] B, int p2, int r2, int k){


    if (p1 > r1) { 
        return B[p2+k-1];
    } else if (p2 > r2) {
        return A[p1+k-1];
    }


    int midA = p1 + (int)Math.floor((r1-p1)/2);// Middle element from subarray A
    int midB = p2 + (int)Math.floor((r2-p2)/2);// Middle element from subarray B

    /**
     * Compare the sum of number of elements from left-subarray up to middle element. 
     */
    if ((midA-p1+midB-p2+2) < k) { 
        // We don't need to the left-subarray based on the comparisons between middle element
        if (A[midA] > B[midB]) {
            return findKth(A, p1, r1, B, midB+1, r2, k-(midB-p2+1)); //
        } else {
            return findKth(A, midA+1, r1, B, p2, r2, k-(midA-p1+1)); //
        }
    } else {
        // We don't need to the right-subarray based on the comparisons between middle element.
        if (A[midA] > B[midB]) {
            return findKth(A, p1, midA-1, B, p2, r2, k);
        } else {
            return findKth(A, p1, r1, B, p2, midB-1, k);
        }
    }
}
```

I felt the strategy I used should be correct. But for the two test cases shown above, it'll print wrong outputs in some particular kth value. So I guessed there must be something wrong with my strategy. Can anyone describe briefly which part of this implementation is not correct? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can solve this problem by using minheap/maxheap ,it is one of  the best way to get kth smallest element

Comment: @Geeky I know there are many other ways to solve this problems. But can you spot where I did wrong for this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already good solutions to this problem on StackOverflow, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607945/how-to-find-the-kth-smallest-element-in-the-union-of-two-sorted-arrays) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686823/given-2-sorted-arrays-of-integers-find-the-nth-largest-number-in-sublinear-time), so I will focus on identifying the bug only:

This line:

```
if ((midA-p1+midB-p2+2) < k) {
```

should be modified to use `<=`:

```
if ((midA-p1+midB-p2+2) <= k) {
```

You can see why this is needed with this small example:

```
A = {1,3}
B = {2}
```

The other variables will be:

```
p1 = p2 = r2 = midA = midB = 0
r1 = 1
```

And so the expression `midA-p1+midB-p2+2` will be `2`. In this case, you clearly want to throw away an element of A, not the only element of B.

Note that in general it is OK to include the *k* case for the execution of the `if` block, as you will never throw away *k* (i.e. too many) elements there: the expression passed as last argument to the recursive call is always at the most *k-1*.

On the other hand, going to the `else` part when the `if` expression is *k*, is wrong, as *midA* or *midB* might well be the index of that *k<sup>th</sup>* element, and it *will* be thrown out there.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct. The program doesn't work for some kth value due to this condition. Sometimes I just found defining these boundary conditions is a bit tricky. The program returns the correct value for all input array and kth value now.

Answer (score 2):

I will update my answer if I can find bug in your snippet. Right now you can take a look of my code which logic is exactly same as yours except:

> The strategy is basically comparing the middle index elements from two
>   subarray based on their length condition.

The major difference for simplicity and small size of my code is I avoided some if-else conditions(for length condition) by calling the function with swapping its parameter in case of first array/index pair is not smaller.

```
public static int findKth(int[] A, int i, int[] B, int j, int k) {

    // Here is the simple trick. We've just changed the parameter order if first array is not smaller.
    // so that later we won't need to write if-else conditions to check smaller/greater stuff
    if((A.length - i) > (B.length - j))
    {
        return findKth(B, j, A, i, k);
    }

    if(i >= A.length) 
    {
        return B[j + k - 1];
    }
    if(k == 1)
    {
        return Math.min(A[i], B[j]);
    }

    int aMid = Math.min(k / 2, A.length - i);
    int bMid = k - aMid;

    if(A[i + aMid - 1] <= B[j + bMid - 1])
    {
        return findKth(A, i + aMid, B, j, k - aMid);
    }

    return findKth(A, i, B, j + bMid, k - bMid);
}

public static int findKthSmallestElement(int[] A, int[] B, int k)
{
    if(k > A.length + B.length)
        return -1;

    return findKth(A, 0, B, 0, k);
}
```

The time complexity is `O(log(m + n))`.

Comment: Just found the bug. Thanks for the efforts anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int findKthElement(int a[],int start1,int end1,int b[],int start2,int end2,int k){
    if(start1 >= end1)return b[start2+k-1];
    if(start2 >= end2)return a[start1+k-1];
    if(k==1)return min(a[start1],b[start2]);
    int aMax = INT_MAX;
    int bMax = INT_MAX;
    if(start1+k/2-1 < end1) aMax = a[start1 + k/2 - 1];
    if(start2+k/2-1 < end2) bMax = b[start2 + k/2 - 1];

    if(aMax > bMax){
        return findKthElement(a,start1,end1,b,start2+k/2,end2,k-k/2);
    }
    else{
        return findKthElement(a,start1 + k/2,end1,b,start2,end2,k-k/2);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        int n,m,k;
        cout<<"Enter the size of 1st Array"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n];
        cout<<"Enter the Element of 1st Array"<<endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
        }
        cout<<"Enter the size of 2nd Array"<<endl;
        cin>>m;
        int arr1[m];
        cout<<"Enter the Element of 2nd Array"<<endl;
        for(int i = 0;i<m;i++){
            cin>>arr1[i];
        }
        cout<<"Enter The Value of K";
        cin>>k;
        sort(arr,arr+n);
        sort(arr1,arr1+m);
        cout<<findKthElement(arr,0,n,arr1,0,m,k)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Time Complexcity is O(log(min(m,n)))