# Find the top k sums of two sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm

You are given two sorted arrays, of sizes n and m respectively. Your task (should you choose to accept it), is to output the largest k sums of the form `a[i]+b[j]`.

A O(k log k) solution [can be found here](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_cs;action=display;num=1132204952;start=). There are rumors of a O(k) or O(n) solution. Does one exist?

Comment: The problem in the link you gave is top n values of A[i] + B[j], A,B are sorted arrays of length n. That need not be the case as stated in this question. In fact in that thread James Fingas (see page 2) has given an O(n) time algorithm (for k=n I believe). +1 anyway.

Comment: @Moron - sorry, confused this with a similar question. I edited this one. Are you sure James' solution is valid?

Comment: @ripper: No, I am not sure, but others on that thread seem to confirm the correctness. Just pointed that out, in case you missed it. You read it and found it lacking?

Comment: @Moron - there are a few solutions that claim to be O(n) in that thread, but none that are both correct and have a really concise explanation, one that I would read and say "ah-ha, now I understand!"

Comment: @ripper: I was a regular at that forum for a few years and I am pretty sure James Fingas was one of the better/saner puzzle solvers there (he was a regular before I frequented it). Of course, I never did make the effort to understand that solution, but given that Hippo (and I believe Grimbal) agree, I would be reasonably confident of the correctness. Of course, that is not proof.

Comment: @Moron - I see, so if I have time for this I'll check his solution more thoroughly. I'm preparing from some Google interviews tomorrow, so I don't have much time to lose...

Comment: @ripper234, I'm actually not so sure an O(k) solution exists.  Suppose for simplicity m = n (size of arrays).  I can construct inputs such that the diagonal from bottom left to top right has all the same value.  Now, I can vary that input slightly such that I can make any one of the elements on the diagonal be greater than the others by 1 (and all elements up and left of the diagonal strictly greater).  Now when you get to the diagonal, how do you choose?

Comment: Please read my answer in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607945/how-to-find-the-kth-smallest-element-in-the-union-of-two-sorted-arrays/29352604#29352604

Answer (score 11):

I found the responses at your link mostly vague and poorly structured.  Here's a start with a <strike>O(k * log(min(m, n)))</strike> <strike>O(k * log(m + n))</strike> O(k * log(k)) algorithm.

Suppose they are sorted decreasing.  Imagine you computed the m*n matrix of the sums as follows:

```
for i from 0 to m
    for j from 0 to n
        sums[i][j] = a[i] + b[j]
```

In this matrix, values monotonically decrease down and to the right.  With that in mind, here is an algorithm which performs a graph search through this matrix in order of decreasing sums.

```
q : priority queue (decreasing) := empty priority queue
add (0, 0) to q with priority a[0] + b[0]
while k > 0:
    k--
    x := pop q
    output x
    (i, j) : tuple of int,int := position of x
    if i < m:
        add (i + 1, j) to q with priority a[i + 1] + b[j]
    if j < n:
        add (i, j + 1) to q with priority a[i] + b[j + 1]
```

Analysis:

1. The loop is executed k times.

   1. There is one pop operation per iteration.
   2. There are up to two insert operations per iteration.
2. The maximum size of the priority queue is <strike>O(min(m, n))</strike> <strike>O(m + n)</strike> O(k).
3. The priority queue can be implemented with a binary heap giving log(size) pop and insert.
4. Therefore this algorithm is <strike>O(k * log(min(m, n)))</strike> <strike>O(k * log(m + n))</strike> O(k * log(k)).

Note that the general priority queue abstract data type needs to be modified to ignore duplicate entries.  Alternately, you could maintain a separate set structure that first checks for membership in the set before adding to the queue, and removes from the set after popping from the queue.  Neither of these ideas would worsen the time or space complexity.

I could write this up in Java if there's any interest.

Edit:  fixed complexity.  There *is* an algorithm which has the complexity I described, but it is slightly different from this one.  You would have to take care to avoid adding certain nodes.  My simple solution adds many nodes to the queue prematurely.

Comment: This is O(m*n) (creation of sum matrix takes O(m*n) OP want's at most O(n + m + k)

Comment: @Saeed, thanks, but I'm not actually creating that matrix.  I'm just describing how I'm imagining the problem.  If you see a problem in the analysis I provided, please point it out.

Comment: Yes, this is an elegant solution. The complexity is actually O(k * log min(k, m, n)) - if k < m, n then the priority queue will only have k elements. Now, I'd like to see a a better solution in terms of complexity.

Comment: @ripper234, you would be correct if I had got the queue size bound right, but unfortunately I think it's actually O(m + n) as I wrote it rather than O(min(m, n)).  It can be made O(min(m, n)) but it requires slightly more work.

Comment: I can see how this could be improved on but I've yet to nail down the details.

Comment: why is the queue size bound is (m+n), it seems to me that it should be  (mn) ?

Comment: Actually, the correct time complexity is klogk. k is # of found elements. So maintain a heap with size of K. Diagonally put elements in the heap util found k elements. There is no need to keep traversing all elements because data_left_side > data and data_up_side>data

Answer (score 1):

```
private static class FrontierElem implements Comparable<FrontierElem> {
    int value;
    int aIdx;
    int bIdx;

    public FrontierElem(int value, int aIdx, int bIdx) {
        this.value = value;
        this.aIdx = aIdx;
        this.bIdx = bIdx;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(FrontierElem o) {
        return o.value - value;
    }

}

public static void findMaxSum( int [] a, int [] b, int k ) {
    Integer [] frontierA = new Integer[ a.length ];
    Integer [] frontierB = new Integer[ b.length ];
    PriorityQueue<FrontierElem> q = new PriorityQueue<MaxSum.FrontierElem>();
    frontierA[0] = frontierB[0]=0;
    q.add( new FrontierElem( a[0]+b[0], 0, 0));
    while( k > 0 ) {
        FrontierElem f = q.poll();
        System.out.println( f.value+"    "+q.size() );
        k--;
        frontierA[ f.aIdx ] = frontierB[ f.bIdx ] = null;
        int fRight = f.aIdx+1;
        int fDown = f.bIdx+1;
        if( fRight < a.length && frontierA[ fRight ] == null ) {
            q.add( new FrontierElem( a[fRight]+b[f.bIdx], fRight, f.bIdx));
            frontierA[ fRight ] = f.bIdx;
            frontierB[ f.bIdx ] = fRight;
        }
        if( fDown < b.length && frontierB[ fDown ] == null ) {
            q.add( new FrontierElem( a[f.aIdx]+b[fDown], f.aIdx, fDown));
            frontierA[ f.aIdx ] = fDown;
            frontierB[ fDown ] = f.aIdx;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is similar to the other solution, but with the observation that as you add to your result set from the matrix, at every step the next element in our set can only come from where the current set is concave. I called these elements frontier elements and I keep track of their position in two arrays and their values in a priority queue. This helps keep the queue size down, but by how much I've yet to figure out. It seems to be about `sqrt( k )` but I'm not entirely sure about that.

(Of course the frontierA/B arrays could be simple boolean arrays, but this way they fully define my result set, This isn't used anywhere in this example but might be useful otherwise.)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have time to read it in detail yet, but you should be able to do it with just one array tracking frontiers.  Choose the one with minimum length.  That should bring you to O(min(m, n) max size for the array and O(k * log(min(k, m, n))) time for the algorithm.  I'll take another look within a day.

Comment: @rlibby I guess you could, but this way a frontier lookup is just O(1) time whichever axis you're interested in.

Comment: The concaveness insight is really nice, but I don't see how it improves worst case space complexity. When the covered part of the matrix takes the form of 1-sized steps, then the candidate set is O(n+m), right?

Answer (score 0):

As the pre-condition is the Array are sorted hence lets consider the following
for N= 5;

A[]={ 1,2,3,4,5}

B[]={ 496,497,498,499,500}

Now since we know Summation of N-1 of A&B would be highest hence just insert this in to heap along with the indexes of A & B element ( why, indexes? we'll come to know in a short while )

H.insert(A[N-1]+B[N-1],N-1,N-1);

now

```
 while(!H.empty()) { // the time heap is not empty 

 H.pop(); // this will give you the sum you are looking for 

 The indexes which we got at the time of pop, we shall use them for selecting the next sum element.

 Consider the following :
 if we have i & j as the indexes in A & B , then the next element would be  max ( A[i]+B[j-1], A[i-1]+B[j], A[i+1]+B[j+1] ) , 
 So, insert the same if that has not been inserted in the heap
 hence
 (i,j)= max ( A[i]+B[j-1], A[i-1]+B[j], A[i+1]+B[j+1] ) ;
 if(Hash[i,j]){ // not inserted 
    H.insert (i,j);
 }else{
    get the next max from max ( A[i]+B[j-1], A[i-1]+B[j], A[i+1]+B[j+1] ) ; and insert.                      
 }

 K pop-ing them will give you max elements required.
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @rlibby and @xuhdev with such an original idea to solve this kind of problem. I had a similar coding exercise interview require to find N largest sums formed by K elements in K descending sorted arrays - means we must pick 1 element from each sorted arrays to build the largest sum.

```
Example: List findHighestSums(int[][] lists, int n) {}

[5,4,3,2,1]
[4,1]
[5,0,0]
[6,4,2]
[1]

and a value of 5 for n, your procedure should return a List of size 5:

[21,20,19,19,18]
```

Below is my code, please take a look carefully for those block comments :D

```
private class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
    String state;

    int sum;

    public Pair(String state, int sum) {
        this.state = state;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        // Max heap
        return o.sum - this.sum;
    }
}

List<Integer> findHighestSums(int[][] lists, int n) {

    int numOfLists = lists.length;
    int totalCharacterInState = 0;

    /*
     * To represent State of combination of largest sum as String
     * The number of characters for each list should be Math.ceil(log(list[i].length))
     * For example: 
     *      If list1 length contains from 11 to 100 elements
     *      Then the State represents for list1 will require 2 characters
     */
    int[] positionStartingCharacterOfListState = new int[numOfLists + 1];
    positionStartingCharacterOfListState[0] = 0;

    // the reason to set less or equal here is to get the position starting character of the last list
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfLists; i++) {  
        int previousListNumOfCharacters = 1;
        if(lists[i-1].length > 10) {
            previousListNumOfCharacters = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(lists[i-1].length));
        }
        positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i] = positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i-1] + previousListNumOfCharacters;
        totalCharacterInState += previousListNumOfCharacters;
    }

    // Check the state <---> make sure that combination of a sum is new
    Set<String> states = new HashSet<>();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // This is a max heap contain <State, largestSum>
    PriorityQueue<Pair> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();

    char[] stateChars = new char[totalCharacterInState];
    Arrays.fill(stateChars, '0');
    sb.append(stateChars);
    String firstState = sb.toString();
    states.add(firstState);

    int firstLargestSum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfLists; i++) firstLargestSum += lists[i][0];

    // Imagine this is the initial state in a graph
    pq.add(new Pair(firstState, firstLargestSum));

    while(n > 0) {
        // In case n is larger than the number of combinations of all list entries 
        if(pq.isEmpty()) break;
        Pair top = pq.poll();
        String currentState = top.state;
        int currentSum = top.sum;

        /*
         * Loop for all lists and generate new states of which only 1 character is different from the former state  
         * For example: the initial state (Stage 0) 0 0 0 0 0
         * So the next states (Stage 1) should be:
         *  1 0 0 0 0
         *  0 1 0 0 0 (choose element at index 2 from 2nd array)
         *  0 0 1 0 0 (choose element at index 2 from 3rd array)
         *  0 0 0 0 1 
         * But don't forget to check whether index in any lists have exceeded list's length
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfLists; i++) {
            int indexInList = Integer.parseInt(
                    currentState.substring(positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i], positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i+1]));
            if( indexInList < lists[i].length - 1) {
                int numberOfCharacters = positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i+1] - positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i];
                sb = new StringBuilder(currentState.substring(0, positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i]));
                sb.append(String.format("%0" + numberOfCharacters + "d", indexInList + 1));
                sb.append(currentState.substring(positionStartingCharacterOfListState[i+1]));
                String newState = sb.toString();
                if(!states.contains(newState)) {

                    // The newSum is always <= currentSum
                    int newSum = currentSum - lists[i][indexInList] + lists[i][indexInList+1];

                    states.add(newState);
                    // Using priority queue, we can immediately retrieve the largest Sum at Stage k and track all other unused states.
                    // From that Stage k largest Sum's state, then we can generate new states
                    // Those sums composed by recently generated states don't guarantee to be larger than those sums composed by old unused states.
                    pq.add(new Pair(newState, newSum));
                }

            }
        }
        result.add(currentSum);
        n--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Let me explain how I come up with the solution:

1. The while loop in my answer executes N times, consider the max heap
   ( priority queue).
2. Poll operation 1 time with complexity O(log(
   sumOfListLength )) because the maximum element Pair in
   heap is  sumOfListLength.
3. Insertion operations might up to K times,
   the complexity for each insertion is log(sumOfListLength).
   Therefore, the complexity is **O(N * log(sumOfListLength) )**,