# Hamming numbers for O(N) speed and O(1) memory

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity, hamming-numbers

Disclaimer: there are many questions about it, but I didn't find any with requirement of constant memory.

Hamming numbers is a numbers `2^i*3^j*5^k`, where i, j, k are natural numbers.

Is there a possibility to generate Nth Hamming number with O(N) time and O(1) (constant) memory? Under generate I mean exactly the generator, i.e. you can only output the result and not read the previously generated numbers (in that case memory will be not constant). But you can save some constant number of them.

I see only best algorithm with constant memory is not better than O(N log N), for example, based on priority queue. But is there mathematical proof that it is impossible to construct an algorithm in O(N) time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12480291/77567

Comment: It's an interesting question, but you may have more luck getting an answer on cs.stackexhange.com since probably it's not possible and you want a proof.

Comment: what is the  O(1) memory O(N log N) time algorithm that you mention? the PQ you mention takes up ~ N^(2/3) space. and BTW the correct standard algorithm (due to Dijkstra) is O(N)-time. even the overproducing algo that you probably refer to can be O(N) if using properly performant PQ with O(1) poop and O(1) insert.

Comment: @robmayoff that's not an O(1) memory either, because of the feedback loops in each node. (and [h/2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12482407/849891) is still ~N^(2/3), just like h/5.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to consider here is the direct slice enumeration algorithm which can be seen e.g. [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126285/generating-integers-in-ascending-order-using-a-set-of-prime-numbers/10160054#10160054), enumerating the triples `(k,j,i)` in the vicinity of a given logarithm value (*base 2*) of a sequence member so that `target - delta < k*log2_5 + j*log2_3 + i < target + delta`, progressively calculating the cumulative logarithm while picking the `j` and `k` so that `i` is directly known.

It is thus an *N<sup>2/3</sup>*-time algo producing *N<sup>2/3</sup>*-wide slices of the sequence at a time (with `k*log2_5 + j*log2_3 + i` close to the target value, so these triples form the crust of the [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) filled with the [Hamming sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) triples <sup>1</sup>),  meaning *O(1)* time per produced number, thus producing *N* sequence members in *O(N)* *amortized* time and *O(N<sup>2/3</sup>)*-space. That's no improvement over the baseline Dijkstra's algorithm <sup>2</sup>  with the same complexities, even *non-amortized* and with better constant factors.

To make it *O(1)*-space, the crust width will need to be narrowed as we progress along the sequence. But the narrower the crust, the more and more misses will there be when enumerating its triples -- *and this is pretty much the proof you asked for*. The constant slice size means *O(N<sup>2/3</sup>)* work per the *O(1)* slice, for an overall *O(N<sup>5/3</sup>)*  amortized time, *O(1)* space algorithm.

These are the two end points on this spectrum: from *N<sup>1</sup>*-time, *N<sup>2/3</sup>*-space to *N<sup>0</sup>* space, *N<sup>5/3</sup>*-time, amortized.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here's [the image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number#/media/File:Regular_divisibility_lattice.svg), with logarithmic vertical scale:

[image]

This essentially is a tetrahedron of Hamming sequence triples `(i,j,k)` stretched in space as `(i*log2, j*log3, k*log5)`, seen from the side. The image is a bit askew, if it's to be true 3D picture.

*edit:* <sup>2</sup> It seems I forgot that the slices have to be sorted, as they are produced out of order by the *j,k*-enumerations. This changes the best complexity for producing the sequence's *N*  numbers in order via the slice algorithm to *O(N<sup>2/3</sup> log N)* time, *O(N<sup>2/3</sup>)* space and makes Dijkstra's algorithm a winner there. It doesn't change the top bound of *O(N<sup>5/3</sup>)* time though, for the *O(1)* slices.