# Find order statistic in union of 2 sorted lists on logarithmic time

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, mergesort

I need some algorithm that find the order statistic (the value of K-th) in the union of 2 sorted lists, on logarithmic time.

I.e. I have 2 sorted lists `A[1..m]` and `B[1...n]`. I need to find the item K in the sorted list which contain the values of the 2 lists, and I need to do that in run time- `O(lg(max(m,n))`.

I know how to do that in run time `O(k)`, by scan the minimalist values in the both lists, until I counted K items.

but I don't know how to do that on `O(lg(max(m,n))`.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I see the solutions in [previous similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607945/how-to-find-the-kth-smallest-element-in-the-union-of-two-sorted-arrays/5202213#5202213), but there aren't working algorithm there. for example for the lists: a=13456, b=278.

So, maybe someone has another idea?