# fast kth element of sorted array implementation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698659/189035) algorithm from [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian), but I try to compile it 
(`gcc/g++ 4.8`) get a strange compiler error:

```
const int n=101,m=31,k=*16-1;
int i;
srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)    x[i]=rand();
std::sort(x,x+m,std::greater<float>());
std::sort(x+m,x+n,std::greater<float>());
float v=nsmallest_iter(x,x+m,x+m+1,x+n,n-1-k,std::greater<float>());
```

## Edit

adding the  `-std=c++11`  flag I get:

```
  from blabla.cpp:2:
blabla.cpp: In instantiation of ‘typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type nsmallest_iter(RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator, size_t, Compare) [with RandomAccessIterator = float*; Compare = std::greater<float>; typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type = float; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
blabla.cpp:58:64:   required from here
blabla.cpp:28:66: error: ‘issorted’ was not declared in this scope
  assert(issorted(firsta,lasta,less) && issorted(firstb,lastb,less));
                                                                  ^
blabla.cpp:28:35: error: ‘issorted’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
  assert(issorted(firsta,lasta,less) && issorted(firstb,lastb,less));
                                   ^
blabla.cpp:28:66: note: ‘issorted’ declared here, later in the translation unit
  assert(issorted(firsta,lasta,less) && issorted(firstb,lastb,less));
                                                              ^
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: what compile flags did you use?

Comment: @Theolodis: -O3 -march=native -mtune=native

Comment: Try -std=c++11 as flag

Comment: @Theolodis: thanks, it solved one of the problems:)

Comment: you should consider to create a new question if you do in fact have a new problem ;)

Comment: Replace `issorted` by `std::is_sorted` (and `#include <algorithm>`)

Comment: Note also that `x[m]` is not part of any sort range.

Comment: @Jarod42: thanks, if you would post your comment as an answer, i'd be happy to accept it: it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `issorted` by `std::is_sorted`.
(Add `#include <algorithm>` if not present)
(Compile with C++11)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a C++11 feature, so you have to either use the compile flag

```
-std=c++11
```

or

```
-std=c++0x
```

for the second problem you are probably missing some header or do have an issue with the code.

edit: issorted does probably refer to [`std::is_sorted`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_sorted/). It is to be found in the include `#include <algorithm>`